# add textfield and textarea when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i got this code from a friend but it only creates a textfield every time the button is clicked. what i want is to create a textfield and a textarea when the button is clicked

```
<input type="button" value="add input "onclick="addInput()"/>

            <span id="responce"></span>
            <script>
            var countBox =1;
            var boxName = 0;
            function addInput()
            {
                var boxName="textBox"+countBox; 
                document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<br/><input type="text" id="'+boxName+'" value="'+boxName+'" "  /><br/>';
                countBox += 1;
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: Add the html for the textarea to the existing code

Comment: modify this line as document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<br/><input type="text" id="'+boxName+'" value="'+boxName+'" "  /><br/><textarea></textarea>'

Comment: i tried it but now it doesnt show anything everytime i click the button @ArunPJohny

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dwhmL4hg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code between your `<head></head>` elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var countBox = 1;

function addInput(){
    var boxName = "textBox"+countBox;
    var spanElement = document.getElementById("responce");

    spanElement.innerHTML +=
        "<br />"+
        "<input type='text' id='"+ boxName +"' value='"+ boxName +"' />"+
        "<br />"+
        "<textarea></textarea>";
    countBox++;
}

</script>
```

And only use this code between your `<body></body>` elements:

```
<input type="button" value="add input "onclick="addInput()"/>
<span id="responce"></span>
```

Code is fully tested and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try This one:

[Demo](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/add-text.html)

```
function addtext() {
    var newtext = document.myform.inputtext.value;
    if (document.myform.placement[1].checked) {
        document.myform.outputtext.value = "";
        }
    document.myform.outputtext.value += newtext;
}
```